# Relation between primary current and secondary currents in a transformer with multiple outputs

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

This applies for a flyback converter working in DCM.

Here is what the following document (https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1024.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535591115e0f6d) has :

[image]

[image]

Here is what I obtained :

[image]

<sub>(Edit: Replaced original image above, with one using improved contrast by Edin Fifić)</sub>

What is the correct answer?

------------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------------------------

My answer is wrong but I am not able to understand why it is wrong.

If you consider a transfomer with two outputs and the number of turn for each winding equal to 1. Suppose a peak of 1A at the primary, then you should have a total peak of 1A at the secondaries. So if the winding are all equal to 1. It would mean 0.5A on each output. My formula doesn't not describe this phenomenom.

Comment: A picture with better contrast (stronger lighting) would make it easier to read.

Comment: I added a better picture ... I cannot do better :( Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Thank you for the picture !

Comment: No problem. I hope someone answers your question.